# Crystal Report View in MVC 5 asp.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report working independently on SAP Crystal report. But now I have to add on my Web application made on Asp.net MVC 5. I just have to add a view on my web application. How I can easily add it?